covariant derivative on pullback bundle and along a curve
Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold with connection $\nabla$, $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ a curve, and $\Gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times [a,b]\to M$ a variation of $\gamma$ with $\Gamma(0,t)=\gamma(t)$. Let $(s,t)$ be the coordinate on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times [a,b]$. From the connection $\nabla$ on $TM$, two covariant derivavtive can be induced:

covariant derivative along $\gamma$, denote it by $\nabla_{t}^{\gamma}$, which sends a vector field along $\gamma$ to a vector field along $\gamma$.
covariant derivative along $\Gamma$, or on the pullback bundle $\Gamma^*(TM)$, denote it by $\nabla^\Gamma$, which sends a vector field $X$ on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times [a,b]$ and a vector field along $\Gamma$ to a vector field along $\Gamma$.

My question is, if we have a vector field $V(s,t)$ along $\Gamma$, then $V(0,t)$ is a vector field along $\gamma$, then do we have the following equation?
$$
(\nabla_t^\gamma V(0,t))(t_0)=(\nabla^\Gamma_{\partial_t}V)(0,t_0)
$$
The differential geometry I've learned is mainly about covariant derivative along a curve, e.g. I have the explicite formula in a chart, but for the case along an arbitrary map, I have no such information. Any ideas are welcom.
